# Detect project language in cmake

Tags: cmake

I'd like to detect the current project language, for example if I have something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (foo VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
```

I need something like this

```
if (project_lang EQUAL "CXX")
  # do something for c++
endif ()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [global property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-of-global-scope) [ENABLED_LANGUAGES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_gbl/ENABLED_LANGUAGES.html):

```
get_property(languages GLOBAL PROPERTY ENABLED_LANGUAGES)
message("languages: ${languages}")
```

for `project(Foo)`, i.e. default values:

```
languages: C;CXX;RC
```

for `project(Foo LANGUAGES CXX)`, i.e. C++ project:

```
languages: CXX;RC
```

for `project(Foo LANGUAGES C)`, i.e. C project:

```
languages: C;RC
```

etc.

The best command to check that the exact language is enabled is `if(... IN_LIST ...)` (available since [CMake 3.3](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/release/3.3.html#commands)):

```
if("CXX" IN_LIST languages)
  message("C++ enabled")
endif()
```

Comment: Just wanted to add the conditional expression: `if ("${languages}" MATCHES "CXX")`. If @Joel want to check for something like `C` I think a more sophisticated regex or an additional `list(FIND ...)` call gets necessary.

Comment: Thanks, both for the help.

Comment: @ruslo Thanks, I didn't know that one.