# How to create a target that requires a language to be enabled by user?

Tags: cmake

I need to make sure that if a user uses my target,

```
find_package(myproject)
```

they have enabled C++. CMake comes with a lot of compile features for different languages but none that check if the language is actually enabled. Currently, my solution is to require compiler support for an old C++ standard:

```
target_compile_features(myproject INTERFACE cxx_std_98)
```

If C++ is not enabled, the user sees the message

```
Cannot use features from non-enabled language CXX
```

which hopefully leads them to enable the language. Is there a better way to propagate the language requirement with an exported target?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect project language in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389273/detect-project-language-in-cmake)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite see how this is a duplicate. The user has no idea that they need to enable C++, but my exported target needs to convey that information somehow.

Comment: Instead of `target_compile_features` you may simply check, whether C++ is enabled, and emit appropriate error if not. Isn't this what do you want? The duplicate question describes, how to check the language.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It's true that you can use the answers of that question to construct something that works for this question, but I disagree that this is a dup. It would be appropriate, however, to answer here, using the answers there as reference (with appropriate attribution)

Comment: The problem is that the *user* package needs to enable the language and I have no control over that. When they include `find_package(myproject)` in their CMake script, it should trigger an error if any of my project requirements are not met. Lets say I need the user to have a C++11 compliant compiler. I include `cxx_std_11` in `target_compile_features`. If their compiler is insuffient they get an error. Similarly, if they don't have C++ enabled, then the line `find_package(myproject)` should trigger an error.

Comment: The solution in the other post involves a GLOBAL PROPERTY. I need something like that but as a target specific property that I can export with my target. I'm starting to think it's probably not doable and our code is actually not very well designed. It's mainly a Fortran code but if certain options are enabled, then some C++ files are also compiled into the library. If another package then uses the library, they need to have C++ enabled on their end.

Comment: you can set enabled languages with the project(Name LANGUAGES CXX) function or with enable_language(CXX) function
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/project.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/enable_language.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XXXConfig.cmake` script may add C++-required targets only when specific COMPONENT is requested, and perform checking for C++ compiler like in that question: [Detect project language in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389273/detect-project-language-in-cmake)

**XXXConfig.cmake**:

```
# ... Generic things about Config file
# ... add `.cmake` EXPORT files *without* targets, required C++ compiler
if(CXX_LIB XXX_FIND_COMPONENTS)
    # User requests C++-specific component of your package
    get_property(languages GLOBAL PROPERTY ENABLED_LANGUAGES)
    if("CXX" IN_LIST languages)
        # C++ compiler is enabled
        # ... add `.cmake` EXPORT files *with* C++-required targets.
    else()
        message(SEND_ERROR "CXX language should be enabled for use CXX_LIB component of XXX package")
    endif()
endif()
```

When call this script with

```
find_package(XXX)
```

no C++ targets will be exported, and no C++ compiler check is performed.

But invocation

```
find_package(XXX COMPONENTS CXX_LIB)
```

will exports all target, and also checks C++ compiler.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So I conclude that there is no simple CMake command or a compile feature to do what I need, but in principle I can include all the necessary logic in the `XXXConfig.cmake` file. Accepting for now but I need to think about if this is the approach we are taking.

Comment: From my understanding, "usage requirements" are useful to enforce some properties of **particular target**, which will use your library. For that purpose `if` command isn't usable, as a user target isn't created yet. But **global properties**, like enabled languages, can be checked with `if`, so usage requirements are not needed for them.